# Apache http client correct thread usage in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have an api method in which I take a file, do some processing and send it to another service using apache http client.

```java
public void myMethod(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    doProcessing(multipartFile.getInputStream); 
    httpClient.sendFile(multipartFile);
}
```

It seems to be working, but the question for me is now how should I configure it so it will be safe to use in Spring boot multi request scenario?
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```java
public void sendFile(MultipartFile document){
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.LEGACY); 
    builder.addPart(
        "id", 
        new StringBody(id.toString(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    );
    builder.addPart(
        "document", 
        new InputStreamBody(document.getInputStream(), ContentType.parse(mediaType))
    );

    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    HttpPost method = new HttpPost("myservice:8080/api/load");
    method.setEntity(entity);
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setExpectContinueEnabled(true).build();
    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();
         CloseableHttpResponse responseHttp = httpClient.execute(method);) {
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(responseHttp.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        response = objectMapper.readValue(json, Dto.class);
// ...
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right usage if there will be multiple concurrent requests. Can I use it like this or I should create one final client field? Are there properties I should configure for the multithread scenario? Tried to search for something in the internet, but didn't find something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: HttpClient is Thread Safe class so it should work in concurrent scenario. If you want to override default config of HttpClient then its one time thing and do it in some method with @bean. you can have dedicated httpClient for each external client.

Comment: @SauriBabu, so I can configure a bean and then autowire it where I want, this is what you're saying? What about using it, should I use it within try() still?

Comment: you got it correct. you can wrap actual API call in try block.  in heavy prod workload sometimes network connection fails so day2 could be adding retry capability in code.

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot, configuire a `RestTemplate` using the Apache HTTP client you want to use. Configure it as an `@Bean` and inject it. Both the `RestTemplate` and the Apache HTTP Client are threadsafe (and relatively heavy to create) so reuse the single instance you have.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think RestTemplate by default uses Java http client. is there any benefit to configure it to use Apache httpClient ?

Comment: That is what is being used in the question. Apache HTTP Client has more options then the default java http client, like connection pooling, caching etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry, I'm not familiar with Rest Template, is it neccessary thing to do or I can just configure Http Apache Client as Bean and use it where I want? What exactly for I need Rest Template if I'm using Apache already?

Comment: `RestTemplate` is an abstraction over multiple HTTP clients, so if you decide to switch, you don't need to rewrite your code.

Comment: Did others find that you need to still use EntityUtils.consumeEntity with the try with stream approach especially for POST requests?  In the past, if we didn't consume the entities it could cause memory leakage as the resources were not released.